# Showing the diagonal in an isosceles trapezoid equals the sum of the product of the two parallel sides plus the square on another side.

Tags: geometry, proof-writing

[image]

I drew this picture to answer the following question:

> Show directly, without the use of Ptolmey's theorem, that in an isosceles trapezoid, the square on a diagonal is equal to the sum of the product of the two parallel sides plus the square on one of the other sides.

What I am trying to show is that $(DB)^2=(DC)(AB)+(AD)^2$

I can show easily that $(DB)^2=(FE)^2+(DF)^2$, but I don't know how to proceed from here. I know that $AF=EB, DF=CE$ and $AB-AF-EB=DC$, but I don't know if any of this helps me.

Any guidance to help me find the right track is helpful!

Comment: That works, you just have to put it all together.

Comment: @Burt Can you please fix the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $AB = a$, $CD = b$, $DF = h$.

Then, $BD^2 = (\frac{a+b}{2} ) ^2 + h^2$
$DC \times AB = ab$
$ AD^2 = (\frac{a-b}{2} ) ^2 + h^2$

We can now verify that the desired equality holds.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you explain the line $BD^2=(\frac{a+b}{2})^2+h^2$?

Comment: @Burt Well, give it a try. How do you think I arrived at that? Is there a natural way to see $BD^2$? Is there a natural way to interpret $(a+b)/2$?

Comment: The way you wrote it reminds me of the area...

Comment: The way to interpret $\frac{a+b}{2}$ is the average base length.

Comment: Yes to the second. For the first, use Pythagorean Theorem instead.

Comment: I see - the length of FB is the average base length because it uses one of the two equivalent "extra pieces" of the bottom base. You used the Pythagorean theorem for the right triangle made by h, FB, and BD.

Comment: You got it!!!!!